# Definitive Android guide to writing to filesDir from MVVM repository (in 2022)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-mvvm

I have the seemingly simple plan to write a JSON file to internal storage while obeying the MVVM architecture. Unfortunately, almost all the focus on StackOverflow, tutorials and the official documentation seems to be on external storage or databases. The rest ignores MVVM or is generally outdated.
After a lot of experimentation where somehow `filesDir` was null, the filesystem was declared as read-only, and I was in a state of general confusion, I settled on a solution which you find as answer below.

#### Problem

I can't decide if my solution below is reasonable or if it has any major drawbacks or violations of MVVM I overlooked. I am absolutely missing some kind of authoritative guide for such a basic task, so I tried to create one here. Please help me make this an up-to-date, industry standard guide for beginners like me!

Comment: "The rest ignores MVVM or is generally outdated" -- access to any particular form of storage is not related to the app architecture, whether that architecture is MVVM, MVP, MVI, or something else. For example, your answer is unrelated to MVVM.

Comment: What I was talking about was stuff like "saving data from inside MainActivity without any Model" in many examples online...  
Also, getting the filesDir requires some kind of Context - one could easily fall into the trap of having the Model dependent on a lifecycle object.  
(In fact, it kinda still is, because setting FILE is not enforced and depends on being set in the Application class. That's partly why I am questioning my solution.)

Comment: "What I was talking about was stuff like "saving data from inside MainActivity without any Model" in many examples online" -- your answer does not have any model classes. If you want in-depth examples, use books and courses more than Stack Overflow answers. "one could easily fall into the trap of having the Model dependent on a lifecycle object" -- many things that are not a `Context` have a lifecycle; those two concepts (lifecycle and `Context`) are not interchangeable.

Comment: "your answer does not have any model classes" -- That is true. I hinted at the Model class with my usage of a repository, which might not be exclusively MVVM, but at least compatible with the idea. "use books and courses" -- I was hoping to get that from Android documentation itself, but wasn't able to find it. Please tell me if you have any particular suggestions!

Comment: On the whole, the documentation focuses on either narrow use cases or very high-level concepts. Some of the step-wise training materials in the docs do a bit better job of depicting those narrow use cases in larger scenarios, but they do not cover everything.

Answer (score 0):

#### My solution

1. Create a Repository singleton (Java style) using a companion object with  `var FILE: File? = null`
2. A `class MyApp: Application()` and inside its `onCreate()` method:
   `Repository.FILE = File(filesDir, "entries.json")`.

> Don't forget to set this application class as `android:name` in the AndroidManifest!

3. A `private var file = Repository.FILE!!` in the "DAO" (my data layer). I feel safe in casting `file` as non-null because `Application().onCreate()` is always called first on startup.
4. Use the `file` variable for actual I/O.

Comment: From a testability standpoint, this approach is not great, as it relies on magic globals (`FILE`) versus injected dependencies that can be faked or mocked. Also, your "always called first on startup" claim [is not completely correct](https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/ov18d2/this_is_why_your_subclassed_application_isnt/). For a trivial example, your approach probably is fine.

Comment: This is the kind of feedback I was hoping for, thanks! Would you mind providing a more solid approach for others to see?

Comment: IMHO, that is not within the reasonable scope of a Stack Overflow answer. FWIW, I cover file I/O in [this chapter](https://commonsware.com/Jetpack/pages/chap-files-001.html) of [this free book](https://commonsware.com/Jetpack).